# How can I make this while loop into a foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to learn PHP and I can't figure out how to convert to following code so it works with foreach. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
$number = $_GET["number"]; 
$total = ($number*($number+1)) / 2; 
$retval = "1"; 
$i=2;

while ($i<=$number) {
    $retval .= ' + ' . $i;
    $i++;
}
echo $retval . " = " . $total . "<br>";
```

Comment: No need for a loop of any kind: `$retval = array_sum(range(1, $_GET['number']));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over an array. You can use [range()](http://php.net/range) to get an array starting from the initial value (`$i=2`) up to the maximum number (i.e. `$number`).

```
$number = $_GET["number"]; 
$total = ($number*($number+1)) / 2; 
$retval = "1"; 
foreach(range(2,$number) as $i) {
    $retval .= ' + ' . $i;
}
echo $retval . " = " . $total . "<br>";
```

You can see this demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/egsi-63ha) - Note that I set the value for `$number` to 6 because we don't have a query string.

Otherwise to simplify it, we could re-write the [*while*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) statement as a [*for*](http://php.net/for) statement:

```
for($i=2; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    $retval .= ' + ' . $i;
}
```

Hopefully the transformation from the while statement is easy to see but if not, perhaps [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) should help.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exacly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

foreach is used to loop an array. not much for counter.
what you wan as alternative probably is for loop

```
for ($i=0;$i<=$number;$i++) {
}
```